# Kinematic question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I am trying to solve Problem 1.20 from Kleppner and Kolenkow book on Mechanics:

[image]

Their solution is:

[image]

which I understand. Notice that this results in $t_0 = 10.08s$ and $t_1 = T-t_0 = 12.50s $.

However, I am trying to solve it in a different way, starting from the position vector.
My reasoning is that we can set up the position equation as a sum of two parts: the accelerating one (white) and the decelerating one (yellow):

[image]

The first bit is:
$$r_1 = \frac{1}{2}a_at_0^2 $$
where $a_a = 7.94 \frac{m}{s^2}$

The second bit (the yellow line) is now at initial velocity of $v_m$ and it's decelerating.
$$ r_2 = r_{tot} - r_1 = v_mt_0 - \frac{1}{2}a_bt_1^2$$

where $v_m$ is the velocity at $t_0$, which is $a_at_0$, and $a_b = 6.86 \frac{m}{s^2}$

So the total position equation becomes:

$$ r_{tot} = 1000 = \frac{1}{2}a_at_0^2 + a_at_0^2 - \frac{1}{2}a_bt_1^2$$

However, this is not right. If I plug the $t_0$ and $t_1$ from the book's solution I get $r_{tot} \sim 854 \neq 1000 $

What's wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$r_2 = v_m t_1 - 0.5a_b t_1^2 $$
not $v_m t_0$ but $v_m t_1$